# os.path.expanduser failing to encode backslash?

Tags: python, windows

In a Python script (executed in 2.7), the second statement returns false, although the directory exists:

```
from os import path
path.exists( path.expanduser('~') )
```

I think this is a backslash problem, since `path.exists(...)` with "hand-coded" home directory using either `/` or `\\` returns true, as expected.

This problem seems to be somewhat specific to my machine, as the same script works fine on other computers (also running Windows).

What causes this behaviour? How can it be fixed without hacking the script (which runs fine on most Windows machines)?

**Update**

The problem is caused by `path.expanduser('~')` wrapping the path in quotes (`"`) on my system, but not on others.

The basic questions remain: Why?

Can this behaviour be changed on my machine without changing the script (which is not maintained by me and works well for everybody else)?

Comment: Well, what is `os.path.expanduser('~`)` on the system you're having trouble on?

Comment: @kindall: Good point! It looks like `path.expanduser(...)` wraps the path in quotes on my system. I mistook them for an artifact of `print`, which is why I did not suspect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `ntpath.py`, the `expanduser()` function first tries to return environment variables `HOME` then `USERPROFILE` in that order, and finally falls back to a composite of `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`, so I'm guessing you have quotes set on one of those environment variables.

Comment: That's it! I checked `USERPROFILE`, but I hat a `HOME` variable set with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import path
path.exists( path.abspath(path.expanduser('~')) )
```

Works? (haven't tested but should replace `\` and `/` issues)

Quote from the Python docs on **path.exists()**:

> Return True if path refers to an existing path. Returns False for
>   broken symbolic links. On some platforms, this function may return
>   False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the
>   requested file, even if the path physically exists.

Comment: Does `path.isdir( ... )` work? and what is your output from `path.expanduser('~')`?

Comment: `path.isdir(...)` returns false, with and without wrapping `abspath` in `expanduser`.

Comment: I identified the immediate problem, see my updated question. The question why this happens inconsistently over several machines remains.